# Wyze SDK: How do I use the refresh token properly?

Tags: python, authentication, sdk, access-token, refresh-token

I'm trying to understand how the refresh_token() function works in the Wyze python SDK:
https://github.com/shauntarves/wyze-sdk/blob/master/wyze_sdk/api/client.py

Let's say I want to access the Wyze API to list all of my devices I have.

First, my python script checks if I have stored an access_token in a file from a previous login. This will remove the need to login again.

If I have one stored, then I simply make calls to the API using the access token I read from the file:

```
wyze_access_token = read_access_token_file()
client = Client(token=wyze_access_token)
response = client.devices_list()
```

If I don't have one stored, I login using Client.login() and then store the access_token and refresh_token it responds with:

```
response = Client().login(
    email="...",
    password="...",
    key_id="...",
    api_key="..."
)
write_access_token_file(response["access_token"])
write_refresh_token_file(response["refresh_token"])
```

In this case, I already have an access_token stored from a previous login. **But it has expired.** So now I need to use the refresh_token() function.

I try to call client.refresh_token() but I am getting an error saying the client is not logged in:

> wyze_sdk.errors.WyzeClientConfigurationError: client is not logged in

It says this because it checks to see if there is a refresh_token assigned to the Client object

..Well, I don't have it assigned to the client, I have it stored in a file. A refresh_token only gets assigned after you execute Client.login()...

But I don't want to login. That takes a ton of time, and using a token is much faster.

Why does refresh_token() not take an argument so I can pass the refresh_token I have stored in a file? I don't get it, why am I required to login again, that completely defeats the purpose of using tokens?

What do I actually do with the refresh_token I got from the login() response initially that I stored in a file?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the source of [`refresh_token`](https://github.com/shauntarves/wyze-sdk/blob/24f422f8d1f3ff9ce8065071519eed391e4e7b24/wyze_sdk/api/client.py#L198-L209) it takes [refresh token](https://github.com/shauntarves/wyze-sdk/blob/24f422f8d1f3ff9ce8065071519eed391e4e7b24/wyze_sdk/api/client.py#L208C43-L208C43) from [`self._refresh_token`](https://github.com/shauntarves/wyze-sdk/blob/24f422f8d1f3ff9ce8065071519eed391e4e7b24/wyze_sdk/api/client.py#L55).
So to re-authenticate with refresh token you can read the token from file first:

```
refresh_token_from_file = read_refresh_token_file()
```

and create a `client` class object by passing `refresh_token` as an argument.

```
client = Client(refresh_token=refresh_token_from_file)
```

Then call `client.refresh_token()` to update the access token using the given refresh token.

```
client.refresh_token()
```

Comment: So I now have this before I make an API call:
    client = Client(refresh_token=refresh_token_from_file,token=access_token_from_file)

I then check to see if the access token expires, and if it does, I do client.refresh_token(), which now gives me this type of response: "'data': {'access_token': 'yhGhrtci...."

Why is it spitting back just an access token? Shouldn't it also give me a new refresh token? Or am I only allowed 1 refresh token per login or something?

Comment: From the code  [`refresh_token`](https://github.com/shauntarves/wyze-sdk/blob/24f422f8d1f3ff9ce8065071519eed391e4e7b24/wyze_sdk/api/client.py#L209) seems to be returning both  `access_token` and `refresh_token`